# How to assign a type to a parameter in python?

Tags: python, class, docstring

I have a class named **triangulo**, and a class named **coord**. So, in a way to create a new instance of triangle, I pass three vertex like

`t= triangle( V1, V2, V3)`

So, for documentation, I want to write the class triangle in this way

```
class triangulo( object ):
   def __init__(self, a:coord, b:coord, c:coord)->None:
       """Constructor
       """
       self.A= a
       self.B= b
       self.C= c

class coord( object ):    
    def __init__( self, x, y ): 
        self.x= x
        self.y= y
```

But when I try to import this library I get this error

*NameError: name 'coord' is not defined*

So the question is: How can I make python accept vertex as a type of data?

Comment: Please post more code, enough to make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the class before using it! so putting `coord` class on the top of `triangulo` will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can either wrap the name of the class in quotes

```
def __init__(self, a: 'coord', b: 'coord', c: 'coord') -> None:
  ...
```

or you can [use a `__future__` import](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/) to do so automatically

```
from __future__ import annotations

...

def __init__(self, a: coord, b: coord, c: coord) -> None:
  ...
```

`from __future__ import annotations` effectively wraps all type signatures in quotation marks to prevent this exact problem. As long as you're not reflexively viewing type annotations at runtime (with something like `MyClass.__annotations__`), you won't even notice, and your type checker will work better.

Answer (score -1):

Note that the type hint can be a class or a type (in your case vertex is a class):

```
from whatever import vertex

class triangle():
    def __init__(self, v1:vertex, v2:vertex, v3:vertex)->None:
        ...
```

More details at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/